# Float a button to the left

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have added ABS to my project and I want to add a button to the far left of this actionbar. I have managed to add a button to the right, by doing this:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.actionbarmenu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch(item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.menuSlider:
            initializeSlideMenu();
            break;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

When the user presses this button, a slidermenu will appear on the screen. But I want this button to be placed to the left of the actionbar. Are there some XML attributes which I need to set? I couldn't find anything regarding this on Google. Maybe I've searched with the wrong searchkeys.

Adding an action to the application icon, see the image beneath:

[image]

Thanks!

**Edit**

I've tried this:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch(item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.menuSlider:
            initializeSlideMenu();
            break;
        case android.R.id.home:
            initializeSlideMenu();
            break;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

the first `case` works fine, but the second case will not trigger the slidemenu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can set an action to the Up Button, but please read this before you set a custom action to the up button: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                // This is called when the Home (Up) button is pressed in the Action Bar.
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Before this will work, you have to enable up with this snippet (add it to the `onCreate` method of your activity):

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Edit: Just re-read the question, showing a SliderMenu is fine. Nevertheless, don't break the design guide.

Comment: I've tried what you suggested, see my edit. Seems that there is no action attached to the application icon.

Comment: See my edit, you missed calling: `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`